# React Native: Lodash Map

Tags: react-native, lodash

I'm new in react native and I want make data function into view.

my function looks like this

```
renderTest = () => {
        <FlatList
            onEndReached={0}
            onEndReached={() => this.handleEnd()}
            >
            {_.map(this.state.leads, (leads, index) => {
                return (
                <Text key={index}>{leads.full_name}</Text>
            )
            })}
        </FlatList>
    }
```

and my View to pass the value of the function

```
<View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
   {this.renderTest()}                      
</View>
```

I don't have any idea what's the problem all I just want is to render the value. I hope could someone help me.

edited

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since you already are in `react world` you can simply use the [**`Array.map`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
renderTest = () => {
    <FlatList onEndReached={() => this.handleEnd()}>
       {this.state.leads.map((lead, index) => {
          return (<Text key={index}>{lead.full_name}</Text>)
       })}
    </FlatList>
}
```

As long as `this.state.leads` is an array.

But bottom line is no `lodash` is needed here.

Comment: I get the error TypeError: this.renderTest is not a function :( btw thanks for welcome :)

Comment: Well you only provided that in your question :). To fix that error you need to post a lot more code to see why that function is not `found`

Comment: I edited my question :) I'm sure my leads is an array :)

Answer (score 0):

As seen by your comment on Akrion's answer, I'm guessing you haven't defined the `renderTest` function inside the component. Another possibility is that you are using a stateless component in which case you cannot access `this`

Answer (score 0):

I'm just not sure you can define a FlatList like that one. I mean, I think you're missing the `return` of the function and you have to pass the property `data` to `FlatList` this way:

```
renderTest = () => {
  return (
    <FlatList
        onEndReached={0}
        onEndReached={() => this.handleEnd()}
        data={this.state.leads}
        renderItem={(lead, index) => <Text key={index}>{lead.full_name}</Text>}
    />
  )
}
```

Let me know if this can solve your issue :)